# Remove pk field from django serialized objects

Tags: django, json, serialization

I'm serializing a bunch of objects with:

```
json = serializers.serialize("json", objects, fields=('name', 'country'))
```

I have not included 'pk' in my fields list, but the produced JSON includes a primary key with each serialized object. I do not want my API to expose primary keys to the general public.

Short of munging the output JSON, what is the correct way to tell `serializers.serialze()` to not include the primary key?

Comment: @Josh Reich What did you end up doing on this one? There's a ticket that talks about it @ http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4656

Comment: I ended up calling simplejson manually

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up working around this by 'manually' achieving what I wanted using the underlying `simplejson` serializer:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
json = simplejson.dumps( [{'name': o.name,
                           'country': o.country} for o in objects] )
```

A little more typing, but works.

Comment: that's fine solution if you just want to dump some data to json and don't care about FK's.

Comment: @Josh It's a lot more coding if you have 28 methods using 5 models in an API.

Comment: I've used this. But it's a hassle when you use this in several views. It's best to use Django's serializers. The last answer has a link to a related question, that explains how to remove the pk and model fields from the objects it generates.

Answer (score 13):

What Josh did but backwards:

```py
data = json.loads(json_string)

for d in data:
    del d['pk']
    del d['model']

data = json.dumps(data)
```

this way you don't have to worry about updating the code when adding more fields in the future.

Answer (score 9):

You may also override JSON serializer as explained here: [Override Django Object Serializer to get rid of specified model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453237/override-django-object-serializer-to-get-rid-of-specified-model)

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer, DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.utils import simplejson

import logging

class MySerializer(Serializer):
    def end_serialization(self):
        cleaned_objects = []

        for obj in self.objects:
            del obj['pk']
            cleaned_objects.append(obj)

        simplejson.dump(cleaned_objects, self.stream, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.options)
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old question, someone else will probably come up with it on a Google search.

Unfortunately the django serializer offers fairly little customization like what you defined. My solution, if you know you will be using a lot of serialization for your project, was simply to copy django's serialization stuff over to my own project and make some small changes. This isn't ideal, but it does the job. Specifically, to remove the pk's, there is a line in start_object(self, obj):

```
self.xml.startElement("object", {
        "pk"    : smart_unicode(obj._get_pk_val()),
        "model" : smart_unicode(obj._meta),
    })
```

Removing the "pk" line should fix it. It's a somewhat dirty hack, since if they improve this later on it may require some changes to your views, but for me this was the easiest way around the limitations.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, so I created my own `Serializer`, inheritance from Serializer from Django.
I'd like only field's data, so I overwrite the method `get_dump_object`, and added the PK field.

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer


class JSONSerializer(Serializer):
    def get_dump_object(self, obj):
        self._current[obj._meta.pk.name] = obj._get_pk_val()
        return self._current
```

And call:

```
output = JSONSerializer().serialize(queryset)
```

Answer (score -1):

The ugly (but working) way  :

```
data_tmp = data.split('{')
#Gets all the data after fields
response = "[{"+data_tmp[2].replace("}}","}",1)
```

Answer (score -3):

We don't waste our time trying to "sanitize" the PK's.  When we produce a JSON record, the PK is there, and the user can ignore it if they want.  They can't do anything with the information, so it's just clutter.

None of our web services interfaces allow anyone to provide a PK back to us.   We do POST, PUT and DELETE searches on other fields, but not the PK.

The HTML, however, shows the PK's the URL's all the time.  It lets people bookmark the pages.

Comment: Many companies assume that no information is contained within sequential primary keys. If you have your access controls locked down, nothing to worry about, right?

Wrong. At the very least, revealing sequential identifiers provides a great way for competitors to keep track of your growth. There is a sizeable industry simply based on finding sequential ID's and selling growth estimates.

Comment: You may approach you problem by using UUID instead of sequential ID's so exposing them to public won't provide any information for competitors.

Comment: Also consider the extra text that is sent to each user when the pk & model is included. This is bandwidth that could quite clearly be saved (especially when sending this to a mobile user).