# Django custon user model/serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a ***Farmer*** model which basically is the extension of ***User***
I want to use first_name & last_name from user in my ***Farmer*** and would like to serialize them as well.

My models.py looks like following:

```
class Farmer(models.Model):

  #Field for refering the default user
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

  def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return "%s the farmer" % self.user.username
```

My serializers.py looks like following:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')


class FarmerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 user = UserSerializer()
 ...
 ...  
 class Meta:
    model = Farmer
    fields = ('user','birth_date', 'email', 'phone_number')
```

For which I get JSON as follows:

{"user": {"first_name": "Jannes","last_name": "Stubbi"},
        "birth_date": "2016-04-13",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "phone_number": "+4912345678"
    },]

***I rather wish to get data as***:

{"first_name": "Jannes","last_name": "Stubbi", "birth_date": "2016-04-13", "email": "test@test.com", "phone_number": "+4912345678"
    }

My views.py

```
  class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
  """
  An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
  """
  def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
    content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
    super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


#view to get the details of all the farmers
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_all_farmers_details(request):

 #Fetch all the farmers from database
 results = Farmer.objects.all()
 #Serialize the obtained results
 serializer = FarmerSerializer(results, many=True)
 return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453072/django-serializers-to-json-custom-json-output-format

Comment: Can you also update `view` class

Comment: Updated with views.py. Essentially serializer should return a data in a clean way and not nested

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like this.

```
class FarmerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name')
    ..
    ..
    class Meta:
        model = Farmer
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email')
```

the trick is to use the 'source' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `serializer.data` returned by the `view`:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_all_farmers_details(request):

    #Fetch all the farmers from database
    results = Farmer.objects.all()
    #Serialize the obtained results
    serializer = FarmerSerializer(results, many=True)

    userDict = serializer.data.pop("user", None)
    if userDict is not None:
        serializer.data['first_name'] = userDict['first_name']
        serializer.data['last_name'] = userDict['last_name']

    return Response(serializer.data)
```