# Django Model Customize Serialization to JSON

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

Default Serializer Implementation:

```
class Serializer(base.Serializer):
    """
    Serializes a QuerySet to basic Python objects.
    """

    internal_use_only = True

    def start_serialization(self):
        self._current = None
        self.objects = []

    def end_serialization(self):
        pass

    def start_object(self, obj):
        self._current = {}

    def end_object(self, obj):
        self.objects.append({
            "model"  : smart_unicode(obj._meta),
            "pk"     : smart_unicode(obj._get_pk_val(), strings_only=True),
            "fields" : self._current
        })
        self._current = None
```

**Data Output Format:**

[{"pk": 2, "model": "android.job", "fields": {"status": "lol", "customer": "HAHA"}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "android.job", "fields": {"status": "lul", "customer": "BWAHA"}}]

My overriding:

```
class MySerialiser(Serializer):
    def start_serialization(self):
        self._current = None
        self.objects = []

    def end_serialization(self):
        pass

    def start_object(self, obj):
        self._current = {}

    def end_object(self, obj):
        self._current['id'] = obj._get_pk_val()
        self.objects.append(self._current)
```

**Output Format:**

{"status": "lol", "customer": "HAHA", id:2L}{"status": "lul", "customer": "BWAHA", id:3L}

**What I need:**

[{"status": "lol", "customer": "HAHA", id:2L}, {"status": "lul", "customer": "BWAHA", id:3L}]

***Note - This is in Django - all of these are of type String! Don't assume they are lists/dicts***

Comment: It appears that you are making this overly complex. [See this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453237/override-django-object-serializer-to-get-rid-of-specified-model)

Answer (score 0):

This worked finally!

```
class MySerialiser(Serializer):
    def start_serialization(self):
        self._current = None
        self.objects = []

    def end_serialization(self):
        simplejson.dump(self.objects, self.stream, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.options)

    def getvalue(self):
        if callable(getattr(self.stream, 'getvalue', None)):
            return self.stream.getvalue()

    def start_object(self, obj):
        self._current = {}

    def end_object(self, obj):
        self._current['id'] = obj._get_pk_val()
        self.objects.append(self._current)
        self._current = None
```